# scala parser combinators (json) in scala js

Tags: json, scala, parsing, scala.js

I'm trying to get the json parser from scala.util.parsing.json to work in scala js and
replaced all that could be the cause of the Uncaught java.lang.RuntimeException: unimplemented error. But so far without success. I cannot find out in chrome and firefox what has to be replaced to avoid the java.lang.RuntimeException: unimplemented error.

Comment: could you post more details about the error? e.g. the complete error message?

Comment: Two causes for unimplemented error were  _.isDigit and _.isLetter; replaced with e.g.:  (s:Char)=> "1234567890".toList.contains(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parser combinator library is currently not included in Scala.js.

However, for Scala 2.11.0-M8, we have a fork of the scala-parser-combinators repo with a scalajs branch where we build it for Scala.js:
https://github.com/sjrd/scala-parser-combinators/tree/scalajs

It's still at the proof of concept stage. When 2.11.0 final is out (which will be any week now), we'll update this repo and publish the artifact so that they can be used by user projects. Currently, you can use it if you clone the repo and `publishLocal` it yourself (and you use Scala 2.11.0-M8 in your Scala.js project).

Sorry for the inconvenience. It'll get better soon.

Comment: As expected, this doesn't work. When I try to run the JSON parser of this fork it throws an unimplemented error. The same with a simplified version of the JSON parser  without any reference to java runtime library.

Comment: What is the status of parser combinator in scala.js? The directory in the repo you refer doesn't seem to exist anymore..

Comment: scala-parser-combinators 1.0.2 is published on Maven Central for Scala.js 0.6.x: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22scala-parser-combinators_sjs0.6_2.11%22 You can depend on it with `"org.scalajs" %%% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.2"`

Comment: FYI there is a slight typo in the dependecy (note the dash in org.scala-js) listed by @sjrd, I had to use: `"org.scala-js" %%% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.2"`